# Disconnecting wifi every few minutes

Tags: 14.04, wireless, networking, dropbox, disconnect

I'm new in Ubuntu and I have some small problem with my wifi. I manage to connect it after an hour of using this forum, however now whatever I'm doing I'm loosing the connection every few minutes. I think it started when I've installed dropbox and all of the software required for it. I have to turn off and again on network to get it for next few minutes.

```
 - Ubuntu version 14.04 
 - asus x550L
 - belkin f7d2301 v1
```

I have logged to another account and everything was fine before I have installed dropbox. 

Any ideas how to fix it? I have such a limited knowledge about this system that I don't even know where to start.

Edit: I have blocked IPv6 and worked without dropbox, problem still occur. I have noticed that it's more likely to appear if I open 2-3 tabs at the same moment, or download update and at the same moment open tab; watch playlist on youtube so it download all the time..

Any ideas how to fix it? I can't believe I have such a problems with linux from the very beginning.

Edit2: should I maybe change my router settings? I have almost default from benkin.
*Dynamic connection on channel 10, bandwidth 20/40, 802.11e/WMM QoS on; wpa-psk+wpa2+psk.*

Edit3: I had enough of it so I have reinstalled system. Same story, installed dropbox which was updating something, using internet and crash after 20sec.

Edit4: I tried to play with MTU, no idea how to change it on my router but I learned that I should have 1472 (+28 = 1500). I added to `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf` two lines:

```
default interface-mtu 1500;
supercede interface-mtu 1500;
```

It didn't change anything. It seems like I'm trying to use too much internet (?). I made limit 1024 kb/s on dropbox and it works. However when I try to update information in "incomplete language support" it crushes..

Comment: Can you append the output of `iw reg get` to your question?

Comment: country US:
 (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (3, 27)
 (5170 - 5250 @ 40), (3, 17)
 (5250 - 5330 @ 40), (3, 20), DFS
 (5490 - 5600 @ 40), (3, 20), DFS
 (5650 - 5710 @ 40), (3, 20), DFS
 (5735 - 5835 @ 40), (3, 30)
 (57240 - 63720 @ 2160), (N/A, 40)

Comment: The only other thing that helped me significantly was fully disabling ipv6

Comment: how can I do that and will it influent somehow mu connection?

Comment: Will need to post it into an answer - will take a couple of minutes.

Comment: Any other suggestion? I'm really stuck with it.

Comment: There was a list of suggestions that started with Ubuntu 13 at [itsfoss](http://itsfoss.com/speed-up-slow-wifi-connection-ubuntu/) - not all of them work for everyone, but the DNS changes also helped me.

Answer (score 3):

Try running this command in terminal:

```
iwconfig
```

If that shows `power management: on` you need to change it to off by running this command:

```
iwconfig [wifi-id] power off
```

Comment: :~$ ifconfig wlan0
wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 46:6a:b6:be:66:fb  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

:~$ ifconfig wlan0 power off
power: Host name lookup failure
ifconfig: `--help' gives usage information.

I'm lost. I tried it even when I didn't see this power management line, but still.

Comment: I have found line powrt management: off after typing iwconfig

Comment: @Crowell okay. Changed it in my answer. If it's set to off, then I don't know what the problem is.

Answer (score 3):

I had an issue with either my ISP or my router - don't really care which it was.  Ipv6 was not being handled well, and causing periodic disconnects.

I disabled ipv6 according to instructions I found on [itsfoss.com](http://itsfoss.com/) - The following lines are added to `/etc/sysctl.conf`

```
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1
```

This is best done from a terminal:  press <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> to open a terminal window, and enter the command `sudo nano /etc/sysctl.conf` to start an editor with the file open.  Add the lines by typing them, or copying them from here (<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> to paste), and press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> to write the file, and <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> to exit the editor.  You will need to reboot for the changes to take effect.

Because I seem to be a little OCD, I also set IPV6 to IGNORE in the NM applet

Comment: I tried it, I made ctrl+o and didn't change the name so I saved 66 lines.. I guess it's ok :) I hope now it'll be fine, if so I will write here during next few days. Thank you for you help!

Comment: I've been watching video on youtube and I was disconnected. I will try to work on one profile without dropbox do be sure that this is the reason..

Comment: It has no connection with dropbox besides the fact that dropbox generate trafic, if it has many files to download internet crash.

Comment: Please run the script that is in the accepted answer in the link below so we may see the information needed to help diagnose the issue.
<http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-can-i-do>

Comment: I've added it here http://askubuntu.com/questions/536468/wifi-disconnects-all-the-time-and-problem-with-nautilus

Comment: @CharlesGreen Worked for me, using ubuntu server in VirtualBox passing it Realtek usb dongle as usb device and connecting to android phone AP, damn ipv6 always causing troubles :) Thanks