# Random drops of the internet connection, while Network stays stable

Tags: 14.04, networking, internet, ethernet, disconnect

Since a while now, I seem to have a weird problem: My laptop (with Ubuntu 14.04) randomly loses it's internet connection, at least 20-30 times a day (for about 1-2 minutes at a time) while the Network connection itself is completly stable (I'm using synergy to share keyboard & mouse, so I would quickly notice if the Network for my laptop was gone).

Now, the issue is: All other computers in the same network are fine (including aother machine with Ubuntu 14.04) and don't loose the internet connection. So it seems to be an issue with the ubuntu on my laptop, not the Network itself (or maybe the router, but I don't have access to it).

I already switched from Wifi to ethernet, disabling wireless, just to make sure that's not the problem - but it didn't help. When I manually restart the network-manager or disable/enable the ethernet connection over the UI, it works again instantly.

I'm not sure what kind of info can help out, but since `lshw -C network` is usually mentioned, here it is:

```
  *-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Ethernet Connection I217-LM
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 19
       bus info: pci@0000:00:19.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 04
       serial: 28:d2:44:bf:ab:ed
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=2.3.2-k duplex=full firmware=0.13-3 ip=192.168.7.141 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:47 memory:f1600000-f161ffff memory:f163f000-f163ffff ioport:4080(size=32)
  *-network DISABLED
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wireless 7260
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 83
       serial: 28:b2:bd:92:d6:fa
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=3.13.0-53-generic firmware=22.24.8.0 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abgn
       resources: irq:48 memory:f1400000-f1401fff
```

I'll add further information based on comments, of course.

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed a file sync program (for instance, Dropbox or ownCloud), try disabling and removing them. After a restart, check if you're still randomly disconnecting. [Me](https://askubuntu.com/questions/799916/connection-drops-periodically-while-running-file-sync-programs) and another [user](https://askubuntu.com/questions/533186/disconnecting-wifi-every-few-minutes) have made the same complaint, and you seem to have the same issues.